# Customized calendar

Tags: c#, calendar

I want to create a calendar as bellow:

1. Some days have a link in their box.
2. If user clicks on each link, a
   video clip plays in Windows Media Player.
3. After creation time, calendar should be not editable.

I can write a C# program for this, but if there is a simpler way? For example dose Microsoft Office provide some tools to create such calendar? do you know similar calendar on the web?

Comment: what kind of project do you want to create? Web... desktop?

Comment: It is not important. I want to do this in a fast and simple way without paying any thing.

Comment: Of course it is important. There are different things you can use depending on what you want to do. It is not the same to use the calendar wpf control, a jquery-calendar or the mvc built-in.

Comment: Assume I need desktop app. But as I told, I need something that solve my problem as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a web application since you mentioned web.

The built-in calendar in .NET is surprisingly extensible, so don't shrug it off. Likewise something like the JavaScript project FullCalendar (disclaimer: not affiliated) may get you much of what you need.

That said the video links will definitely be custom but should be fairly easy to implement as hyperlinks or buttons. Consider a modal overlay to play them in.

I can add more detail but your question is a bit vague as it stands.

Comment: Is there a simpler way? I want a way that without programming do it. for example using microsoft office

Comment: In that case, I think your best option would be to find an HTML or Microsoft Word calendar template (or something similar), and then just add in the links that you want. I really don't think it's going to get any easier, or involve less work, than that.

Comment: HTML template is a good idea! I will wait some hours and if nobody give better solution then I will mark your solution as answer. Thank you @trnelson

Comment: @Merta you're welcome. There should be many templates online, and HTML is very easy to customize. You likely won't find a calendar that does exactly what you need, but HTML is probably the best format to customize it to do what you are asking. Best of luck, and let me know if I can provide further details.